# ValidateThis EqualTo ClientFieldName JavaScript Validation

Tags: coldfusion, autocomplete

The title sucks, I'm sorry.

It takes a little bit to setup my problem, so I'm going to try and simplify it.

My form uses structure notation.

```
<input  type=   "text"
        name=   "bank[routing_number]"
        id=     "bank_routing_number"
        value=  "#rc.bank[ "routing_number" ]#"
        autocomplete=   "off"
        maxlength=      "9" />

<input  type=   "text"
        name=   "bank[routing_number_confirmation]"
        id=     "bank_routing_number_confirmation"
        value=  "#rc.bank[ "routing_number_confirmation" ]#"
        autocomplete=   "off"
        maxlength=      "9" />
```

The ValidateThis rules work fine on the server. I'm running on ColdFusion 9.0.1.

The problem I have is the JavaScript code generated by ValidateThis.

This is the JavaScript rule for EqualTo.

```
fm['bank[routing_number_confirmation]'].rules('add',{"equalto":":input[name='routing_number']","messages":{"equalto":"Bank ACH Routing Numbers (ABA) must match."}}); fm['bank[routing_number_confirmation]'] = $(":input[name='bank[routing_number_confirmation]']",$form_register_new);
```

The relative bit is this:

```
":input[name='routing_number']"
```

I'm expecting this code to be:

```
":input[name='bank[routing_number]']"
```

Here are the ValidateThis rules for routing_number and routing_number_confirmation.

```
    {   "name":             "routing_number" ,
        "clientFieldName":  "bank[routing_number]" ,
        "rules":            [
            {   "type":             "required" ,
                "failureMessage":   "Bank ACH Routing Number (ABA) is required."

            } ,
            {   "type":             "rangelength" ,
                "params":           [
                    {   "name": "minlength" ,   "value":    "9" } ,
                    {   "name": "maxlength" ,   "value":    "9"} ] ,
                "failureMessage":   "Bank ACH Routing Number (ABA) is 9 digits."

            }

        ]

    } ,

    {   "name":             "routing_number_confirmation" ,
        "clientFieldName":  "bank[routing_number_confirmation]" ,
        "rules":            [
            {   "type":             "required" ,
                "failureMessage":   "Confirm Bank ACH Routing Number (ABA) is required."

            } ,
            {   "type":             "equalTo" ,
                "params":   [
                    {   "name":     "comparePropertyName" ,
                        "value":    "routing_number" }
                ] ,
                "failureMessage":   "Bank ACH Routing Numbers (ABA) must match."

            } ,
            {   "type": "rangelength" ,
                "params":   [
                    {   "name": "minlength" ,   "value":    "9" } ,
                    {   "name": "maxlength" ,   "value":    "9"} ] ,
                "failureMessage":   "Bank ACH Routing Number (ABA) is 9 digits."

            }

        ]

    }
```

This is the load order for ValidateThis scripts.

```
// jQuery and jQuery Validate are loaded.

#getColdboxOCM().get( "ValidateThis" ).getInitializationScript(
    JSIncludes= false )#

// Other ValidateThis scripts

#getColdboxOCM().get( "ValidateThis" ).getValidationScript(
    objectType= "registration/bank-account" ,
    formName=   rc.form.name )#
```

The other JavaScript rules for routing_number and routing_number_confirmation work just fine. I've added some custom rules to get around the issue, but is there a way I can fix this using ValidateThis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question on the ValidateThis Google Group and got a prompt response.

http://groups.google.com/group/validatethis/browse_thread/thread/2b18af00d3f5ce98

This was a bug within ValidateThis, but was corrected and is now part of the development branch in github.